# Maven versions plugin update to next snapshot

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use the maven versions plugin to update my pom to the next snapshot version. eg. `0.0.1` should change to `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`.

From my reading of http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html I would expect `mvn versions:set -DnextSnapshot=true` to do this, but in reality it just prompts me for a new version with a default of the current version (`0.0.1`). Am I missing something here? I want to do this update as a part of a script so don't want any manual intervention.

I'm using v2.5 of the versions plugins. That link above says that `nextSnapshot` is available from 2.10 but 2.5 seems to be the latest I can find.

Comment: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/207

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this issue. I got to know that my Maven project was picking up older version (2.3) of Versions Plugin. This no longer seems to be a problem in latest version (2.7) of the plugin.

I added following in pom.xml of my project to force my project use 2.7 version of Maven Versions plugin.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>       
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Otherwise, you can mention latest version of Versions plugin to choose in command line :- `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set -DnextSnapshot=true`

Comment: I think the name is `versions-maven-plugin`: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.codehaus.mojo%20AND%20a:versions-maven-plugin